# Forwarding a Localhost:Port to an ExternalIP:NewPort

Tags: networking, iptables

We have got an application running on our linux server. From that application, when we try and access localhost(127.0.0.1):localport, it should be forwarded to an external IP. Users will only try and access the localhost on a certain port which will be automatically forwarded. 
I read up on iptables nat table, but PREROUTING and POSTROUTING will not be applicable if am right since I am accessing a port on localhost from localhost itself which doesn't touch the network interface at all. Wondering OUTPUT table might be useful but when I tried some combinations, it didn't work. Am I using the right thing or is it not possible at all to do it?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Local traffic goes over the loopback interface (usually `lo`). You should be able to set up iptables rules over it.

Comment: user40524 - Am wondering why did you change the style and removed "Thank you" as well? Is there any specific reason that it has to be the style you have edited as?

Comment: [Have a look here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have figured to do this myself.

2 rules and a flag should be set to achieve this.

Example used here is for `telnet localhost XXXX`, should forward packets to `Ext.er.nal.IP:YYYY`.

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1`

This flag unfortunately exists only on quite latest Linux kernels and not available on an old kernel (there isn't any alternate flag as well in the old kernel). Am quite not sure which exact kernel is the flag available from though. I believe it is available on kernel versions 3.XX.

This flag is to consider the loopback addresses as a proper source or destination address.

[Source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt) for ip sysctl command.

`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport XXXX -j DNAT --to-destination Ext.er.nal.IP:YYYY`

The above command will alter the packets that is to `localhost:XXXX` with the destination IP as `Ext.er.nal.IP:YYYY`

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

The command will alter the source IP as the public ip of your machine.

You could make your rules a bit more strict by adding appropriate source and destination IP and interfaces using `-s`, `-d`, `-i` and `-o`. See `man iptables`.

Thanks to John WH Smith and Wurtel. Suggestions were very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way of accomplishing this is to install `netcat` and `inetd` (Debian has this in `openbsd-inetd`).

Add a line to `/etc/inetd.conf`:

```
127.0.0.1:1234 stream tcp nowait root /bin/nc nc ex.ter.nal.ip 1234
```

Replace the `1234` with the real port number and `ex.ter.nal.ip` with the real external IP address. You may need to append `.1000` or some larger number to the `nowait` option if more than 128 connections per minute need to be made; this is to prevent runaway connections from loading your system unneccessarily.

I also have `-q 4 -w 10` as `nc` options as that helps in my situation, but you might not need it.

Reload `inetd` after modifying the `inetd.conf` file.

Doing it this way uses `nc` started by `inetd` as a relay process, which works quite well.

Comment: Your suggestion is very helpful. Our server has xinetd which is not a problem. I configured its conf file but did not manage to make it work still. Unable to find the reason as why its not working. I'd like to avoid using another application to forward request since it takes up resources. Our application can establish more than 500 connections which should run continuously without interruption. I think xinetd establishes a process for each connection which could potentially take upto 500+ threads. Is there a way through iptables itself though? (looking into John WH Smiths suggestion as well)

Comment: I've tried once with `iptables` but gave up quite soon and used my `inetd` trick. I've just done a little research and apparently it needs to be done in the `nat` table `OUTPUT` chain with a `-j DNAT --to-destination ex.ter.nal.ip:port`